# Select Layer By Attribute using loop

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy

I have 273 features in the feature class and i want to select them one by one and use the statement in the following code.

At the line:

```
*arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc1,"NEW_SELECTION","OBJECTID=79")*,
```

The feature whose object id is 79 one of the features. When i use this code, I do it for only that feature. I want to apply the statement to all features one by one with a loop. I try to do it, but i am new for programming with python.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "D:\pomme de terre 2\pomme de terre2.gdb"
env.overwriteOutput = 1

fc1 = "Flowlin24K_sl_Uns"
fc2 = "New_Poyline"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc1,"NEW_SELECTION","OBJECTID=79")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fc1,"INTERSECT",fc1)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc1,"REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION","StreamLevel>6")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc1,"hidden")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc1,"CLEAR_SELECTION")

coordList = []

arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management("hidden", "vertices", "MID")
arcpy.AddXY_management("vertices")
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("vertices")

for row in rows:
    X = row.getValue("POINT_X")
    Y = row.getValue("POINT_Y")
    coordList.append([X, Y])

del row, rows

coordList.sort()

point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()

for feature in coordList:
    point.X = feature[0]
    point.Y = feature[1]
    array.add(point)

polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)

array.removeAll()
arcpy.Delete_management("vertices")
arcpy.Delete_management("hidden")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polyline, fc2)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?  I can't see just what you want to do?

Answer (score 7):

You can pull this off, but it's my understanding that you can't run selections on feature classes, only on feature LAYERS.

> From ESRI: The input must be a feature layer or a table view. The
>   input cannot be a feature class or table.
>   [ESRI SelectLayerByAttributes Help files](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000071000000)

Your code requires a `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()`
[ESRI MakeFeatureLayer Help files](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Make_Feature_Layer/00170000006p000000/)
**Remember to delete the feature layer at the end of the loop**

Since you've already got an understanding of search cursors, you could just use the cursor to identify the OID for each loop -- this would eliminate the possiblity of your index being out of range.  Each time you loop through your code, change your where clause to the current row's OID.

If you're just getting into Python for ArcMap I HIGHLY recommend checking out [Penn State's Online GIS Master's Program](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/)  -- It's open courseware through the MIT Creative commons license.

Answer (score 4):

did you try looping from start point sth like this:

```
for a in range(0,274):
    obj = "OBJECTID=%s" % (a)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc1,"NEW_SELECTION",obj)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fc1,"INTERSECT",fc1)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc1,"REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION","StreamLevel>6")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc1,"hidden")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (fc1,"CLEAR_SELECTION")

    ...
```

it should solve your problem...

Comment: it has a problem at the line 'obj = "OBJECTID=%s" % (a)' The problem may be the identification of OBJECTID before. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Aragon N I think your index would cause an overflow. There are only has 273 features. OIDs begin at 0 if I am not mistaken. Therefore, your range should just be (0, 273) as the last feature would have an index of 272.

Comment: You could also use `GetCount_management` to get the true feature count, then use that for the range.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Iterate Feature Selection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000000s000000.htm) using [ModelBuilder](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp00000002000000.htm)?  Once you have your model working you can export out the code to python.

Comment: Model iterators are not exported to Python. "If your model used an iterator, the iteration logic will not be exported and will have to be replaced with the looping statements in Python." From [Exporting a model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w00000031000000)