# Calculating Commute Between Residential Address and Childcare address

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, arcgis-10.8, measurements

[image]

I have an Excel sheet (10,000 + rows) that has the residential address and the provider address.

I am trying to see the distance a parent travels to drop their child off to their specific provider. I know I would need to geocode for both locations, but I am not sure how to get the measure between those two points.

I created a unique ID for each row thinking I would need a unique ID as I want the measure for each row. I wanted something like point distance, but it doesn't do 'many points to many points,' meaning one provider (I have about 500 providers on the list) could have 20 kids attending.

I don't use GIS much.

Comment: Do you want the actual driving distance or straight line distance? Can you add a screenshot showing a sample from the excel file?

Comment: @BERA straight line distance should be sufficient. I add the screenshot of the headers, but I don't have the geocoded part in this dataset yet. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Once you have converted your data into a point dataset you could use the generate near table tool to give you straight line distance between pairs of points.

Comment: @Hornbydd Wouldn't near just give me an output against each residential x each provider address. I just want the one to one if that makes sense.

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that your looking for many to many rather than one to one. Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite broad, therefore here is the general workflow idea. If you are stuck with one or more specific task, please ask one question per task

1. [geocode your addresses](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/geocoding-a-table-of-addresses-in-arcmap.htm)
2. project your points in a local projected coordinate system
3. [Loop on the providers to a) select by attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20728/select-layer-by-attribute-using-loop) the residential addresses commuting to the provider and b) get the distance to this particular provider using the "near" or the "generate near table" tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the straigth line distance, it might be possible to merely calculate that from the coordinates themselves in excel? Something like this:

- get coordinates, probably best in UTM (since UTM is in meters instead of degrees)
- Xh, Yh → home adress; Xp, Yp → provider coordinates
- Distance = sqrt(|Xh-Xp|²+|Yh-Yp|²)
- probably round the results down to .1 km so you don't give the illusion of "1m-exactness", if this is just about travel distances this should not matter too much imo. Also adress geocoding might already introduce an error of a few (tens of) meters.

This depends on the scale of your data though, I wouldn't recommend it if it stretches beyond one UTM slice or if you need a much more exact result.

Also depending on the scale and exact question of your research, straight line might not be the best approach, depending on your research area and the used modes of transport. Rivers,  train lines, Highways? Other prohibiting features for travel? Then you should try to get a network dataset of your roads (best including pedestrian and bicycle connections) and do it along this.